# javascript and css button doesn't work on first click & Flexbox

Tags: javascript, css, flexbox

Background:
I'm working on a page for an artist and I've run into some interesting behavior with the site.

I'm using flexbox rather than bootstrap for the layout because the site is pretty small and doesn't have a ton of elements.  Flexbox has been great for  laying out the site especially with respect to changes for different media sizes.

In the smallest media size, however, the mobile layout, I'm having some trouble.  I like the look of the collapsible menu from bootstrap but because I'm not using bootstrap, I got the icon from font awesome and now I'm trying to work in the collapsible menu properties manually using JavaScript and CSS.  But, without using bootstrap, I'm not sure why my expandable menu only works after repeated clicks, not on the first click.

Expectation:
In the smallest media query (window <768 pixels), i have the default mobile layout set up the way I want it.  The banner sits about half way down the page, and the hamburger menu is fixed to the top of the browser.  When I click the menu button the reaction I'm expecting is to have the menu links appear below the menu button and for the page banner to disappear.

Problem:
 This happens and toggles but only after clicking multiple times.

questions:
1. what is causing the clickable behavior to only function after a few clicks?
2. why won't the display property of 'none' apply to the 'nav-left' item?
3. when the menu displays, other than using margin to offset the menu items that appear, is there a way to ensure that they appear below the hamburger button area? (i.e. i want links 1-3 to show up below the hamburger menu when they appear).

[jsfiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/teb8fjxn/16/)

```js
function menuToggle() {
  var x = document.getElementById('nav-right');
  var y = document.getElementsByClassName("nav-left");
  if (x.style.display == "none") {
    x.style.display = "flex";
    y.style.display = "none";
  } else {
    x.style.display = "none";
    y.style.display = "flex";
  }
}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

html,
body {
  background-color: gray;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.nav-left {
  font-family: 'Kristi', cursive;
  font-size: 5.5em;
  color: #e319b6;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0 0 0 50px;
}

.nav-left a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #e319b6;
}

.hamburger {
  display: none;
}

li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
}

li a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #e319b6;
}

li {
  padding: 50px 10px;
  list-style: none;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.7em;
  font-weight: 100;
  color: white;
  display: inline-block;
}

@media (max-width:767px) {
  .hamburger {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 2% 0;
    display: flex;
    color: white;
    font-size: 2em;
    justify-content: center;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
    position: absolute;
    cursor: pointer;
    border: none;
  }
  .pagenav {
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    flex-direction: column;
  }
  .nav-left {
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    order: 2;
    margin-top: 10%;
    padding: 0;
  }
  #nav-right {
    display: none;
    justify-content: center;
    width: 100%;
  }
  .nav {
    width: 100%;
  }
  nav ul {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    width: 100%;
  }
  nav ul li {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    width: 100%;
  }
  nav ul li {}
  nav ul li:hover {
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .8);
  }
  nav ul li:hover a {
    color: #e319b6;
  }
}
```

```html
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title></title>


  <!-- Font Awesome -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.1.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-lKuwvrZot6UHsBSfcMvOkWwlCMgc0TaWr+30HWe3a4ltaBwTZhyTEggF5tJv8tbt" crossorigin="anonymous">


</head>

<body>

  <div class="pagenav">

    <div class="nav-left">
      placeholder
    </div>

    <button class="hamburger" onclick="menuToggle()">
                  <i class="fas fa-bars"></i>
              </button>

    <nav id="nav-right">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="reel.html">Link 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Link 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Link 3</a></li>
      </ul>

    </nav>

  </div>


</body>
```

Comment: Your script has an error: `y` gets an HTMLcollection, not an element. You probably want `y[0]`

Comment: would you suggest i instead give the div an 'id' for targeting and replace the y target with a getElementById for that target 'id'?  For whatever reason, it seems to work even targeting the class collection i've specified but just not on the first click.

Comment: The reason it's not working on the first click was explained by chbchb55, since in the first pass of the function it reads `x.style.display` and this equals `""`, and not `"none"`. If it did equal `"none"`, then it would work in the first pass

Comment: But I don't think you should change the HTML, I think you should change the JavaScript. I'll write an JavaScript answer

Comment: Is it really important to make `.nav-left` a class?

Comment: why is the x.style.display == "" and not "none"?  Wouldn't the property be set to "none" from the media query for the applicable size (in this case  @media (max-width:767px))?

Comment: @Debojyoti not necessarily but at this point changing it has some interesting implications on code not listed here.

Comment: Then just grab the reference by using first index `var y = document.getElementsByClassName("nav-left")[0];` @PanayiotisSpanos

Comment: @PanayiotisSpanos about it being assigned `"none"`: actually no, but your logic is good. The thing is the DOM element attribute JavaScript is modifying in style is not set to anything by default. Your logic is: well, it should read the CSS values or whatever values the element display has. But it doesn't, by default it has none (`""`), only when you change it via JavaScript it has anything

Answer (score 3, accepted):

chbchb55 already explained what's wrong, but I don't think you should change your HTML to fix a bug in the JavaScript code. Rather, change your `menuToggle` function to this here:

```
function menuToggle() {
  var x = document.getElementById('nav-right');
  var y = document.getElementsByClassName("nav-left")[0]; //changed to get the first element of the HTMLCollection
  if (x.style.display == "none" || x.style.display === "") { //changed to also accept the original value, which is "" instead of "none"
    x.style.display = "flex";
    y.style.display = "none";
  } else {
    x.style.display = "none";
    y.style.display = "flex";
  }
}
```

Just to be clear, let me rephrase the sollution: the first time you call your `menuToggle` function, it reads `x.style.display` and its value is actually `""` and not `"none"` as you seemed to be expecting. Since it is not `"none"`, it runs the `else` clause and goes on to assign `x.style.display` to `"none"` and `y.style.display` to `"flex"`. This shouldn't happen, because this signifies that your menu is closed. So only on the second call it opens it, because the first call of the function ran the `else` clause and closed the (already closed) menu.

---

*Adendum*:
chbchb55 also suggested an ingenious optimization, using `if (!'none'.indexOf(x.style.display))` or even creating a prototype as syntactic sugar to make this more readable. I'd still argue against using this for 2 reasons.

First, it is still less readable than `if (x.style.display == "none" || x.style.display === "")`. Here whoever reads the code can immediately see that we are checking for 2 conditions, and only these 2. Using `indexOf`, it's not immediately clear that we are also checking for `""`, so we'd have to specify this in a comment. It's worse for readability, in my opinion.

Second, if speed is an issue, this here is actually the fastest sollution, substituting the `if` for the `else` clause:  `if (x.style.display === "flex")`, then do what's now in the `else` clause. This way, `else` will catch `x === ''` and `x == 'none'` and whatever else. If length of the code is an issue, we could improve this further using the ternary operator:

```
function menuToggle() {
  var x = document.getElementById('nav-right');
  var y = document.getElementsByClassName("nav-left")[0]; //changed to get the first element of the HTMLCollection
  x.style.display === "flex" ? (x.style.display = "none", y.style.display = "flex") : (x.style.display = "flex", y.style.display = "none");     
}
```

Still, speed and length are not an issue here, as the code is now. If it improved 1ms I'd be impressed. I think the original solution is the most readable one, that's why I'd still suggest it as answer. Nevertheless, thinking of using `indexOf` was pretty clever, and if I'm not mistaken it's faster than ES6 `includes`

Comment: this does work but again is there an explanation for why it works on the second click and not the first as is?  It seems odd to me that it doesn't "see" the media query display attribute on the first click but suddenly "sees" it on the second.

Comment: @PanayiotisSpanos I provided an explanation now, but if you're still in doubt tell me and I'll try to be clearer

Comment: Your explanation makes perfect sense.

Comment: accepting as the answer because you were the first to explain what was going on and because your suggested change works to fix the problem.

Comment: not sure if you have time for a follow-up but if you do, any idea on if there's a better way to achieve this using only JS, HTML, CSS?  seems like doing it this way brings in other complications, like when you go to resize the window after having clicked the menu button.

Comment: @PanayiotisSpanos I'd be glad to help, but we should avoid doing many comments on unrelated things. I'll create a chat room in a moment and invite you to it

Comment: @PanayiotisSpanos Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174579/discussion-between-flen-and-panayiotis-spanos).

Answer (score 4):

### The issue is in the HTML, not your function

The problem you're encountering is that `if (x.style.display == "none")` should pass the first time around, because it's hidden right? Well, it isn't passing because, according to the `style` attribute, `display` does not equal `none`, therefore, you can't tell that it's hidden. To fix this just do:

```
<nav id='nav-right' style='display: none'>
```

Now you're code knows that `#nav-right` is hidden and will work on the first click.

### Option 2, Modify the code:

You can use a one-time toggle variable. With this, the first time the button is clicked it will show the menu and then set the toggle variable to false. Like so:

```
let firstMenuClickToggle = true

function menuToggle() {
  ...
  if (x.style.display == 'none' || firstMenuClickToggle) {
    firstMenuToggle = false
    ...
```

### Option 3, check for empty string and `'none'` at the same time

As @flen has said, you can search for an empty string alongside `'none'`, but why not do both at the same time.

For example, try replacing your `if` statement with the following:

```
if (!'none'.indexOf(x.style.display)) {
```

This is actually, from my tests with [Benchmark.js](https://benchmarkjs.com/), significantly faster than @flen's separate comparisons, almost a **Five Second difference** when each is run 10,000 times.

This works because both of the strings `''` and `'none'` exist in `'none'` technically, therefore, if either of these values are there, they will return `0`. As such, I have used the `!` operator to check for this, `!0` will always return true but any other number (i.e. `!-1`) will return false.

### Edit: Making it more readable

```
String.prototype.emptyOrEqualTo = function(string) {
  return string.indexOf(this)
}

// in your function
if (x.style.display.emptyOrEqualTo('none')) {
```

While modifying `String.prototype` is not usually done it does produce a higher readability than most other methods of increasing readability. In fact, you could even throw an `is` onto that and it would be a sentence.

```
display.isEmptyOrEqualTo('none')
```

Now you can actually read it:

**If display is empty or equal to "none"**

---

FYI, in your JSFiddle, `y.style` is `undefined` because you used `.getElementsByClassName` but that returns an array and you didn't get the first index of the returned array.

Another few notes:

- I would suggest using more descriptive variable names than `x` and `y` as they do not communicate their meaning, you have to lookup their definition line to understand, which is not exactly a "best practice".
- You should probably move your javascript to a separate file like you've already done with your CSS.
- Optional: I would suggest learning to use `const` and `let` as well.
- Keep on keeping on, you're doing great.

Comment: wait, this property is set in the css under the @media (max-width:767px).  If i apply it inline where you suggest, the menu wouldn't display at other media sizes no?

Comment: You could use `!important` to override the inline style here.

Comment: Or use a variable to make sure that if it's the first time the button is being pressed, display it, not hide.

Comment: this last suggestion is an interesting work around (it fixes some things and creates another issue which is outside the scope of this question).  But I'm still curious why it doesn't recognize the display property from the media query once it's at the appropriate size?

Comment: IMHO, I think that creating another variable (`fisrtMenuClickToggle`) just to make a first pass possible is kind of an overkill when you can simply specify in the `if` condition that `|| x.style.display === ""`. I think this improves readability and it's a better coding practice because if you do this many times in your code you create a bunch of unnecessary variables, which makes the code less readable. Just my 2c

Comment: Oh true, @flen I wasn't thinking about what `.style.display` returned when there was no value attached to it.

Comment: This is a function that will not be run in a loop and as such it's pointless to optimize it for speed as long as it doesn't take too long.

Comment: @Sandro Well, the `.indexOf` version ran at 7 seconds and the other at 12 seconds. So if it's almost 2 Times as fast then I think it might be worth it.

Comment: as long as a single execution doesn't make the program lag (which won't happen with this as it's just one line of code O(1) and not affecting the DOM) it doesn't really matter, and readability should be prioritized.

Comment: also if you run code multiple times the JS compiler begins to optimize so the result you got when running your code 10'000 times isn't necessarily the time one execution will need times 10'000. And even if that were the case 0.7ms vs 1.2ms is basically nothing.

Comment: @chbchb55 Cool optimization! I commented on it in my edited answer on why I think it was a smart idea, but not the best sollution to OP's case